# Change border color of bootstrap select (btn class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-select

I'm using this library: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/ but I can't change its behavior when selected. For example

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

where `selectpicker` is the key that creates this structure:

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-new" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="blabla" title="Mustard" aria-expanded="true">
<div class="filter-option"><div class="filter-option-inner"><div class="filter-option-inner-inner">Mustard</div></div> 
</div>
</button>
```

So, mainly, the library creates a button over the select (that exists but hidden). What I want is that when i select one of the items on list the border color (of the button and not the select) change color in `#BF69B2`
I have tried in this way:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn dropdown-toggle btn-default")[0].style.borderColor = "#BF69B2";
```

but with no success. Any idea?

Comment: can you post a working example in fiddle or snippet

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to retrieve element with classess `btn dropdown-toggle btn-default`, but in template you have another classess: `btn dropdown-toggle btn-new`.

Just change

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn dropdown-toggle btn-default")[0].style.borderColor = "#BF69B2";
```

to

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn dropdown-toggle btn-new")[0].style.borderColor = "#BF69B2";
```

Comment: I'll try but is there any way to know when the select is triggered?

Comment: Yes, you can create  `onchange` event handler for your select element.

Comment: Ok wait, i got it but not at all! Your answer is correct! But, I've got another problem. I have 3 select. In this way the code works only for the first one because of [0]. Is there any way to loop the select and put the style to everyone when needs?

Comment: and think about that only if the select is selected has to change the border color